# html css margin(white spaces at webpage edges)

Tags: html, css, margin

Basically I got problem with the edge of my website, it got this white spaces :

http://sadpanda.us/images/1885204-15X1WA4.jpg

While I want that web to look like this :

http://sadpanda.us/images/1885205-VG8KJ23.jpg

no white spaces.

Any idea where I've done wrong?

Comment: You're probably not using a reset stylesheet. Be aware, that browsers will use their own default styles for various elements, like `<body>` for example - http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ it's usually a good idea to use something like reset.css or normalize to start with a consistent baseline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks very much like the default `margin` on the `<body>`.

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Should solve it for you.

---

### Quick Demo:

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #ddd;
}
```

[**DEMO WITH SPACE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/2Lzj6/)

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0; /* This will stop the margin, setting it to 0 */
}
div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #ddd;
}
```

[**DEMO WITHOUT SPACE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/2Lzj6/2/)

Comment: Added onto your answer, hope you don't mind. Just added a demo.

Answer (score 0):

each browser has some style for elements like body,h1...etc,that is called as user agent style sheet, they have some margin, if you want reset all css just use universal tag and put margin:0 ... like below..

```
*{ margin: 0;}
```